# WSO2sp on linux does not save the file properly

Tags: wso2-streaming-integrator

I've installed wso2sp 4.2.0 on Linux server, opened the editor, created my first siddhi file and saved it. I named it "CargoWeightApp" and expected to find it in the default `<SP_HOME>/wso2/editor/deployment/workspace` directory. But the file was saved in `<SP_HOME>/wso2/editor/deployment` directory with name `"workspace\CargoWeightApp.siddhi"`.
Any idea why it happened so?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue.
I installed wso2sp 4.2.0 on a remote linux server and I accessed the editor using my Windows desktop. 
It is somehow getting the backslash "\" from Windows and trying to save it in Linux.
I don't have the same issue using a Linux desktop. Please try.

I hope it solved your issue.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

The issue is tracked through [#732](https://github.com/wso2/product-sp/issues/732)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved with PR:[#1380](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics/pull/1380)